# Docker & Php - .env (оркружающая среда)

Tags: php, docker, .env

Хочу передать в php, который находится в контейнере, переменные среды, в которых содержится пароль и данные для подключения к mysql.

Файл среды называется **.env**. Пробовал вот так:

```
  php:
    build: ./php
    volumes:
      - ./html/:/var/www/html
    expose:
      - "9000"
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    env_file: .env
```

И потом в php:

```
<?php var_dump(getenv('MYSQL_DATABASE'));?>

<?php var_dump(getenv('MYSQL_USER'));?>

<?php var_dump(getenv('MYSQL_PASSWORD'));?>
```

Вывод:

bool(false)

bool(false)

bool(false)

Запускаю из Dockerfile-а для PHP таким образом:

```
COPY ./test.php /var/www
RUN php /var/www/test.php
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что не так делаю

.env файл:

```
MYSQL_DATABASE=opencart
MYSQL_USER=opencart
MYSQL_PASSWORD=password
MYSQL_PORT=3306
MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
```

Comment: .env файл покажите. У меня данная история работает.

Comment: @zalex :
обновил вопрос

Comment: Все хорошо и в нем, может конечно от версии ещё зависеть. Environment variables defined in the .env file are not automatically visible inside containers. To set container-applicable environment variables, follow the guidelines in the topic [Environment variables in Compose][1], which describes how to pass shell environment variables through to containers, define environment variables in Compose files, and more.

Comment: нужно определиться, а точно ли вам нужно запускать php-скрипт при создании image.
указанная в Dockerfile команда "RUN php /var/www/test.php" выполняется именно в процессе создания image.
поэтому переменные из .env недоступны

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте таким образом

```
version: '2.0'
services:
  ldap_server:
    image: my-image
    container_name: my-image
    restart: unless-stopped
    env_file:
      - .env
```

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но этот способ точно не поможет. В последнем комменте вопроса указали причину. А решение - использовать ARG в Dockerfile, либо передавать окружение в явном виде через командную строку.